# XSLT Pivot Dynamic columns

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to group and pivot input XML data and convert into JSON, I have most of working, other than the what I consider the dymanic column name 
This is my current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:text>{"root":{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"Table":[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Metric[@TableName != '']" group-by="@measObjLdn">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="curr_key" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[@TableName!='']" group-by="@TableName">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:text>{"TableName":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"Stamp":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@BeginTime"/>
                <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"measObjLdn":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$curr_key"/>
                <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"Element_Type":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Element_Type"/>
                <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"Key1":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Key1"/>
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:for-each select="@ColumnName">
                            <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            <xsl:text>":"</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@measResult"/>
                            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>]}}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is a sample in file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Metric measType="50332573"
           infoid="50331655"
           measResult="768"
           h50332573="768"
           BeginTime="2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00"
           measObjLdn="THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0"
           Element_Type="ULGROUP"
           Key1="THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0"
           TableName="HH_CORE_BASE"
           ColumnName="VSCEULAVAILABLEULGROUP"
           VSCEULAVAILABLEULGROUP="768"/>
   <Metric measType="50332574"
           infoid="50331655"
           measResult="14.65"
           h50332574="14.65"
           BeginTime="2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00"
           measObjLdn="THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0"
           Element_Type="ULGROUP"
           Key1="THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0"
           TableName="HH_CORE_BASE"
           ColumnName="VSCEULMEANULGROUP"
           VSCEULMEANULGROUP="14.65"/>
   <Metric measType="50342574"
           infoid="50331655"
           measResult="8.5"
           h50342574="8.5"
           BeginTime="2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00"
           measObjLdn="THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0"
           Element_Type="ULGROUP"
           Key1="THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0"
           TableName="HH_CORE_BASE"
           ColumnName="VSCEULMINULGROUP"
           VSCEULMINULGROUP="8.5"/>
   <Metric measType="50342575"
           infoid="50331655"
           measResult="23.5"
           h50342575="23.5"
           BeginTime="2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00"
           measObjLdn="THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0"
           Element_Type="ULGROUP"
           Key1="THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0"
           TableName="HH_CORE_BASE"
           ColumnName="VSCEULMAXULGROUP"
           VSCEULMAXULGROUP="23.5"/>
   <Metric measType="50342635"
           infoid="50331655"
           measResult="0"
           h50342635="0"
           BeginTime="2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00"
           measObjLdn="THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0"
           Element_Type="ULGROUP"
           Key1="THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0"
           TableName=""/>
</root>
```

The output from the XSLT is a follows, however I'm missing value from the column i.e. "VSCEULMEANULGROUP":"14.65", is it easier to code using the static ColumnName and measResult (which is not working for me) or "VSCEULMEANULGROUP"="14.65" from the XML

```
{
  "root":{
    "Table":[{
        "TableName":"HH_CORE_BASE",
        "Stamp":"2016-12-29T23:30:00-07:00",
        "measObjLdn":"THAB23626/ULGROUP:UL BB Resource Group No.=0",
        "Element_Type":"ULGROUP",
        "Key1":"THAB23626/ULGROUP:=0",
        "VSCEULAVAILABLEULGROUP":"",
        "VSCEULMEANULGROUP":"",
        "VSCEULMINULGROUP":"",
        "VSCEULMAXULGROUP":""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want more people to study the question, consider simplifying it. We don't have to wade through 20 attributes with names like VSCEULAVAILABLEULGROUP when the problem could be illustrated perfectly well with two attributes called foo and bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that in:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@ColumnName">
  <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>":"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@measResult"/>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the context is the `ColumnName` attribute which doesn't/can't have an attribute named `measResult`. You need to go back up to the parent/containing element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@ColumnName">
  <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>":"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="../@measResult"/><!--CHANGED THIS LINE-->
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank, yes I knew I needed to go up the hierarchy but didn't know how